# How to convolve a signal with itself$ x[n]*x[n]$

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

Q. For $ x[n]$ as given in Fig Q1, determine $x[n]*x[n] $

$x[n] = {-2,2,3,0,2}$

---

[image: Graph]

---

I'm not sure if there has been a mistake but there isn't another impulse response or anything given so I can only assume this is one purpose but I have no idea where to begin. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start with the definition of (discrete-time) convolution.